# is VMware the reason for my gazebo not responding issues?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-ros, launch

i installed gazebo through a tutorial from articulated robotics, it was  sudo apt install ros-humble-gazebo-ros-pkgs. i used the command  ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py.
it was working for many times but now, even if i reinstalled it, it isnt working. i am using ubuntu 22.04 ros2 humble, VMware with 8 gigs of RAM.
How do i fix this issue? will i have to reinstall VMware and reset all my ubuntu files?
here is the error im getting,
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [5393]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [5395]
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1711635730.065184567] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[ERROR] [gzclient-2]: process has died [pid 5395, exit code -2, cmd 'gzclient'].
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process[gzserver-1] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: sending signal 'SIGTERM' to process[gzserver-1]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1711635735.071952147] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=15)
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process[gzserver-1] failed to terminate '10.0' seconds after receiving 'SIGTERM', escalating to 'SIGKILL'
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: sending signal 'SIGKILL' to process[gzserver-1]
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process has died [pid 5393, exit code -9, cmd 'gzserver -slibgazebo_ros_init.so -slibgazebo_ros_factory.so -slibgazebo_ros_force_system.so'].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.